# simple way to copy recordset from fdquery to fdquery

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, firedac

Using fireDac, is there a simpler way to copy FDQuery to FDQuery?

the current hardcoded solution is to map each field in code to eache other field in code and post and edit and such.

```
var
FDQueryThis,FDQueryOther:TFDQuery;
begin
  FDQueryThis.active:=true;
  FDQueryOther.active:=true;
  FDQueryThisNamelyField.AsInteger := FDQueryThis.NamelyField.AsInteger;
// some more fields
FDQueryThis.post;
end;
```

Is there a tool or a function that provide this service?
I did see CopyRecord as a member of TFDQuery, howver how to create a record For TFDQuery?

Comment: TFDQuery.CopyDataSet?

Comment: In `TDataSet` there is a function `CopyFields`, but that will still require to call `Edit` and `Post` on the target dataset. CopyRecord does something similar. What do you mean with _create a record for TFDQuery_?

Comment: could you please provide an example code? if we skip the mapping it is a 90% of the work. the edit and post is the small part.

Comment: Copying one record is plain simple (assuming the fieldnames and fieldtypes are equal and you want to copy the contents of the current record of sourceDS into the current record of targetDS): `targetDS.Edit;`  `targetDS.CopyFields(sourceDS);` `targetDS.Post;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just use CloneCursor method,

```
FDQueryThis.CloneCursor(FDQueryOther, True, False);
```

[Here You've got full description](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FireDAC.Comp.DataSet.TFDDataSet.CloneCursor)

However keep in mind the physical data stays the same. if you want to copy the data to a different location use .Data property:

```
FDQueryThis.Data := FDQueryOther.Data;
```

Best regards

Comment: The Documentation is not so good, when they wrote "Share" it means they use the same data and point to it from diffrent direction. a share is like var variable in procedure call, while expection of clone is the non var parameter in procedure call.

Comment: You use CloneCursor if You wish to get the same physical data, but different index, filtering options etc. If You want Just copy data into another dataset, use FDQuery.Data property and resulting dataset is afterwards independent.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this answer is incorrect. The following code raises an exception in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, reporting that 'CommandText must not be empty.' EmployeeConnection is active, and EmployeeTable is active.

    var
      FDQuery: TFDQuery; 
    begin
      FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create ( Self );
      FDQuery.Connection := EmployeeConnection;
      FDQuery.CloneCursor( EmployeeTable );

Comment: In this case both queries are active : ("  FDQueryThis.active:=true;
  FDQueryOther.active:=true;") So answer is correct but You are right that in case of cloning into query You must set up command text (even like : 'select 1' ) which is being run before actually cloning cursor. One might find deeper analysis of cloning cursors in erm.. Your article :) : http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29416